# Avoid calling twice to the same nested query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run this query:

```
 select productID,t.[year]  
 from (
     select ProductID, [year] = year(DT), howMuch = count(*) 
     from [CONTAINS] as c
     join ORDERS as o on c.OrderID = o.OrderID 
     group by ProductID, year(DT) 
 ) as t      
 where howMuch >= all (
     select howMuch
     from ( 
         select  ProductID, [year] = year(DT), howMuch = count(*) 
         from [CONTAINS] as c
         join ORDERS as o on c.OrderID = o.OrderID
         group by ProductID,year(DT)
     ) as k
     where t.[year] = k.[year]
 )
```

Well, it works. but I want to avoid using the same select query twice. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? That looks more like MS SQL Server.

Comment: It could be Sybase ASE, or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your database is SQL Server. If this is the case, you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression), something that was designed for this case.

Your query can be nicely simplified to:

```
with
q as (
  select ProductID, [year]=year(DT),howMuch=count(*) 
  from [CONTAINS] as c join ORDERS as o on c.OrderID=o.OrderID 
  group by ProductID,year(DT) 
)
select productID, t.[year]  
from q as t      
where howMuch >= all (
  select howMuch from q as k where t.[year]=k.[year]
)
```